# RAT Addition and Multiplication?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

If RAT = (R+A+T) × R×A×T,then what is RAT?

Are there possibilities other than 000, 135, 144?

Comment: This user is asking questions an ongoing contest! Please flag it for deletion.

Comment: @ABcDexter [This post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/questions-from-on-going-contests/1678#1678) contains the policy regarding contest questions.  If you can provide a link to a contest containing this question that meets the criteria in the meta post linked above, the post will be locked until the contest is complete.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

> No, there are no other solutions than the ones you found.

I got this by brute forcing it with this code:

```
Dim r As Integer  
Dim a As Integer  
Dim t As Integer  
Dim rat As Integer  

For r = 0 To 9
    For a = 0 To 9
        For t = 0 To 9
            rat = r * 100 + a * 10 + t
            If rat = (r + a + t) * r * a * t Then
                Console.WriteLine(rat)
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Hey look at that! Someone actually uses Visual Basic for stuff! Take that Tucker!